# MongoDB get avg from each arrayelement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

dbsample:

```
var doc1= new BsonDocument
{
    { "line", "a" },
    { "size", new BsonArray { 2 } }
};
var doc2= new BsonDocument
{
    { "line", "xx" },
    { "size", new BsonArray { 5, 3, 8} }
};
var doc3= new BsonDocument
{
    { "line", "xx" },
    { "size", new BsonArray { 1, 10, 8} }
};
```

I want to group the BsonDocument by line, get the count of each line and the avg of every BsonArrayElement. Grouping and count works but how can I get the avg of every BsonArrayElement? The length of the BsonArray vary between the different lines.

```
var filterBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate().Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$line" }, { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } });
foreach (var document in aggregate.ToEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine(document);
}
```

Output that I want:

```
{ "_id" : "xx", "count" : 2, "avg" : [3, 6.5, 8] }
{ "_id" : "a", "count" : 1, "avg" : [2]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired result, you'd need to construct and run an aggregation pipeline that has the following operators:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$line",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "doc": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$doc" },
    { 
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$doc.size",
            "includeArrayIndex": "arrayIndex"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "line": "$doc.line",
                "idx": "$arrayIndex"
            },
            "avg": { "$avg": "$doc.size" },
            "count": { "$first": "$count" }            
        }
    }, 
    { "$sort": { "_id.idx": 1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.line",
            "count": { "$first": "$count" },
            "avg": { "$push": "$avg" }
        }
    }     
])
```

**C# Implementation (untested):**

```
var result = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Group(new BsonDocument { 
        { "_id", "$line" }, 
        { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) },
        { "doc", new BsonDocument("$push", "$$ROOT") }      
    })
    .Unwind(x => x.doc)
    .Unwind(new BsonDocument { 
        { "path", "$doc.size" }, 
        { "includeArrayIndex", "arrayIndex" }   
    })
    .Group(new BsonDocument { 
        { "_id", new BsonDocument {
            { "line", "$doc.line" },
            { "idx", "$arrayIndex" }
        } }, 
        { "avg", new BsonDocument("$avg", "$doc.size") },
        { "count", new BsonDocument("$first", "$count") }       
    })
    .Sort(new BsonDocument("_id.idx", 1))
    .Group(new BsonDocument { 
        { "_id", "$_id.line" }, 
        { "count", new BsonDocument("$first", "$count") },
        { "avg", new BsonDocument("$push", "$avg") },
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you. The code works in the shell but in c# I get an error "'BsonDocument' does not contain a definition for 'doc' and no extension method 'doc' accepting a first argument of type 'BsonDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, I haven't tested this. When I get the chance I will but you might need to debug the pipeline especially on this step `.Unwind(x => x.doc)` which may need refactoring.